# iPhone 4 support for MRT or Multiple Rendering Targets (opengl es)?

Tags: iphone, ipad, opengl-es

I've been searching on Google for a definite answer but haven't found it yet: Does the iPhone 4 (A4 chip) support Multiple Rendering Targets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does not.

See: http://www.imgtec.com/forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=678&PID=2464

You can also inspect the iOS SDK headers and find that there is no GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT greater than 0.

---

While Max's answer is correct regarding the ability to create multiple rendering context. Multiple render target refers to simultaneously rendering to multiple color buffers from a single frame buffer object. This is important because rendering simultaneously from multiple threads duplicates the workload instead of simply allowing the final stage of pixel shader to write different components to separate buffers. For instance, when using MRT diffuse, normals, and positions can be simultaneously written to separate buffers for deferred rendering.